# aws - how to list availability zones for all regions?

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services

I want ot go through regions and list all the availability zones for each one.

I have (ruby)

```
  result='Zones:<br/>'
  ec2 = Aws::EC2::Client.new(region: 'us-east-1')

  puts "Amazon EC2 regions:\n\n"
  describe_regions_result = ec2.describe_regions()
  describe_regions_result.regions.each do |region|
    puts "Region: #{region.region_name}"

    Aws.config.update({region: region.region_name})
    azs = ec2.describe_availability_zones #  (region_name: region.region_name)
    azs.availability_zones.each do |zone|
      result+="#{zone.region_name} - #{zone.zone_name}<br/>"
      p zone.region_name + ' ' + zone.zone_name
    end 
  end
```

but my output keeps showing the individual AZs all being in region us-east-2 and repeating as the same values, as in

```
Region: us-east-1
"us-east-2 us-east-2a"
"us-east-2 us-east-2b"
"us-east-2 us-east-2c"
Region: us-east-2
"us-east-2 us-east-2a"
"us-east-2 us-east-2b"
"us-east-2 us-east-2c"
Region: us-west-1
"us-east-2 us-east-2a"
"us-east-2 us-east-2b"
"us-east-2 us-east-2c"
    ...
```

How to fix to show the az's within each region ?

I tried adding on `(region_name: region.region_name)` to the line

```
azs = ec2.describe_availability_zones(region_name: region.region_name)
```

but that gave an error

```
ArgumentError at /bucket_counts
unexpected value at params[:region_name]
```

and also, as shown, I tried

```
Aws.config.update({region: region.region_name})
```

but that didn't help. Of course I don't want to use config change if possible just to listr the az's for the regions.

Answer (score 0):

As a temporary workaround I recreate the ec2 client every time, as in

```
    ec2 = Aws::EC2::Client.new(region: region.region_name)
```

within the `region` iterator

This is obviously not ideal but does produce the desired output:

```
Amazon EC2 regions:                                                                                                              

Region: eu-north-1                                                                                                               
"eu-north-1 eu-north-1a"                                                                                                         
"eu-north-1 eu-north-1b"                                                                                                         
"eu-north-1 eu-north-1c"                                                                                                         
Region: ap-south-1                                                                                                               
"ap-south-1 ap-south-1a"
"ap-south-1 ap-south-1b"
"ap-south-1 ap-south-1c"
Region: eu-west-3
"eu-west-3 eu-west-3a"
"eu-west-3 eu-west-3b"
"eu-west-3 eu-west-3c"
```